# How can I access the most recent entry in the Azure Storage Table using python sdk?

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-tablequery

I am using the following code:

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService
from azure.cosmosdb.table.models import Entity

table_service = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')

task = table_service.get_entity('table1', '71cb50aa-75ac-4363-a14e-26df95c9b418', 'SCHEDULE')
print(task)

task2 = table_service.query_entities('table1', filter=None, select=None, num_results=1, marker=None, accept='application/json;odata=minimalmetadata', property_resolver=None, timeout=None)

print(task2)
```

But while writing python code, I do not know the partition key.
I want to check if the latest entry into the table 'table1' contains 'SCHEDULE'.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to know how to use function [`query_entities(table_name, filter=None, select=None, num_results=None, marker=None, accept='application/json;odata=minimalmetadata', property_resolver=None, timeout=None)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.tableservice?view=azure-python#query-entities-table-name--filter-none--select-none--num-results-none--marker-none--accept--application-json-odata-minimalmetadata---property-resolver-none--timeout-none-) as the figure below to list the latest entites of the table `table1` with `SCHEDULE` RowKey value.

[image]

As I known, you need to realize it with the `filter` parameter, as the code below.

```
filter = "RowKey eq 'SCHEDULE'
task2 = table_service.query_entities('table1', filter=filter)
print(list(task2))
```

The code above will list all entites with `RowKey` `SCHEDULE` and unknown `PartitionKey`, please refer to the offical document [`Querying Tables and Entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Querying-Tables-and-Entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to know more details for using the `filter` parameter.

However, due to there is not support for sorting the entities by `Timestamp`, you can not get the latest entity directly by `filter` and `num_results=1`. If there is a pattern to know the timestamp range of the latest entities, you can try to use the code below.

```
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

filter = "RowKey eq 'SCHEDULE' and Timestamp lt datetime'{}'".format(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()) # such as `2019-07-29T07:41:40.897643`
# Or filter = "RowKey eq 'SCHEDULE' and Timestamp ge datetime'<the start of datetime range>' and Timestamp lt datetime'<the end of datetime range>'"
task2 = table_service.query_entities('table1', filter=filter)
    print(list(task2))
newlist = sorted(task2, key=itemgetter('Timestamp'))
latest_entity = newlist[0]
print(latest_entity)
```

If you want a simple solution, I think Azure Function with Table Storage trigger will helps, please refer to the offical document [`Azure Table storage bindings for Azure Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table) which supports Python.

Hope it helps.